# Why does the program run in command line but not with IDLE?

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle, reddit

The code uses a Reddit wrapper called praw
Here is part of the code:

```
    import praw
    from praw.models import MoreComments
    username = 'myusername'
    userAgent = 'MyAppName/0.1 by ' + username
    clientId = 'myclientID'
    clientSecret = 'myclientSecret'
    threadId = input('Enter your thread id: ');
    reddit = praw.Reddit(user_agent=userAgent, client_id=clientId, client_secret=clientSecret)
    submission = reddit.submission(id=threadId)
    subredditName = submission.subreddit
    subredditName = str(subredditName)
    act = input('type in here what you want to see: ')
    comment_queue = submission.comments[:]  # Seed with top-level
    submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)

    def dialogues():
     for comment in submission.comments.list():
        if comment.body.count('"')>7 or comment.body.count('\n')>3:
            print(comment.body + '\n \n \n')  

    def maxLen():
     res = 'abc'
     for comment in submission.comments.list():
        if len(comment.body)>len(res):
            res=comment.body
     print(res)
     #http://code.activestate.com/recipes/269708-some-python-style-switches/
     eval('%s()'%act)
```

Since I am new to Python and don't really get programming in general, I am surprised to see that the every bit of code in the commandline works but I get an error in IDLE on  the first line saying ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'praw'

Answer (score 0):

you have to install praw using the command

`pip install praw` which install latest version of praw in the environment

Answer (score 0):

What must be happening is that your cmd and idle are using different python interpreters i.e., you have two different modules which can execute python code. It can either be different versions of python or it can be the same version but, installed in different locations in your machine.

Let's call the two interpreters as PyA and PyB for now. If you have `pip install praw` in PyA, only PyA will be able to import and execute functions from that library. PyB still has no idea what `praw` means.

What you can do is install the library for PyB and everything will be good to go.